# how to pass arguments to listeners in lit-element?

Tags: polymer, lit-element, lit-html

```
<div @click=${this.click_cb.bind(this, record)}>${record.msg}<div>
```

Is this the correct way to pass an argument to a listener?

Answer (score 10):

You should also be able to do this

```
<div @click=${() => this.click_cb(record)}>${record.msg}<div>
```